# The class don't remain on page refresh, i use cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, addclass

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
        var cookieName = 'SalveazaIDtr_';

        if (cookieName) {
            $('#' + cookieName).addClass('selectListItemReaded');
        }
        $('.selectListItem').bind('click', function(e) {

            var id = $(this).attr('id'),
                cookie = cookieName + id;


            $(this).addClass("selectListItemReaded");
            $.cookie(cookieName + $(this).attr('id'), id, {
                expires: 7
            });

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Hi, i have set the script for multiple cookies for each link, the class .selectListItemReaded it's added on click but it's not persist on page refresh.
The cookies are saved , I tested in firebug.

Ex: Cookie

```
Name: SalveazaIDtr_child-0
Value: child-0
Expire:07/16/2015, 12:06:17 PM
```

What is really mistake in my code ?

Thanks

Comment: Really mistake in your code is you did not align! `:P`

Comment: why use document.ready function twice ?

Answer (score 0):

This condition always becomes true:

```
var cookieName = 'SalveazaIDtr_';

if (cookieName) {
    $('#' + cookieName).addClass('selectListItemReaded');
}
```

And you are not checking the cookie and adding the classes to the elements.

Comment: can you help me with the final code? i'm beginner and tough while before I managed to c ode.